# Docusign REST API template variables

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template in docusign and I need to pre-populate some of the fields before sending it for signing using REST api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please read the following guidelines on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  You are more likely to get answers by including more information in your question, a clearer title, and showing what you've tried already.  Any sample code you have will also help get an answer out quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, let's say you have a template with template ID `44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA`, a template role name (i.e. placeholder name) of `Signer1` and you are trying to populate two text tabs with tabLabels of `ApplicantName` and `ApplicantSSN`.

To send a signature request to recipient `"Sally Doe"` and populate her name and SSN on the form you can use the following request:

```
{
    "accountId": "12345",
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "sally.doe@email.com",
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "roleName": "Signer1",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                        "value": "Sally Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value": "12-345-6789"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```